# Does Planck's constant imply limits to computing *results*

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, computational-physics, approximations

... I don't mean quantum effects limiting hardware fabrication sizing. Such small scales have for some time exhibited issues.

Rather, along the lines of imagining the smallest possible divisions of the **universe's most *tiny* physical ruler**: its smallest markings would have to be larger than the Planck length. (Yes?) (For the sake of simplicity, assume the division lines have no width.)

Two interrelated questions:

> **Question 1:** **Could the divisions of this physical ruler be exactly ℓP** or would they have to be only just slightly larger, or some multiple of ℓP ?

E.g. similar conceptually to the [Nyquist Frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) in audio, i.e. the sample size would have to exceed ℓP by some *factor* before the divisions become *accurate*.

> **Question 2a:** Does being **limited** to that smallest physical **approximation** interval ultimately imply that ***models*** of Planck-level activities must inherently have some (subtle?) systemic, Heisenberg limitation affecting their combinatoric ***results*** ?
>
> (Question 2b:  Is question 2a really just a computer science version of aspects of the [measurement problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem)?)

Comment: What? Single precision can do math on 1e-37 level (which is sub-planckian); double precision can do math down to 1e-307 levels (see [this excellent article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)). Outside of this, I am confused what you are actually asking here (specifically towards Q1).

Comment: @KyleKanos - thx for the prompt reply - I edited Q1 ... I really mean a real ruler as a physical object. RE2 I'll read that article ... I am well aware of precision - actually, as you likely well know, the precision is limited only by the code and the machine. I mean are the models, regardless of precision, truly unable to model correctly because we can't check literally, so the model can never be verified without some inherent uncertainty? (I understand bounding.)

Comment: The link explains the reasons why precision is the way it is. It is, as far as I can tell, unrelated to the HUP or Planckian limits (assuming they are limits, which may not actually be true). The reason models cannot be verified is because there often are no *analytic solutions* for the problem. The few analytic solutions that *do* exist are test cases for codes, and the differences that arise are generally due to algorithms and the aforementioned precision.

Comment: @Howard In your last comment, are you referring to the uncertainty principle? If Planck's constant was zero, there would be no fundamental limit to 'certainty' in that sense of the phrase.

Comment: @CuriousKev - yes. Kyle Kanos' comments are helping me to articulate this better. Is HUP possibly *a* reason analytic solutions for Planck-level models might not be found, or perhaps even do not exist?

Comment: What do you mean by "analytic solutions for Planck-level models"?  I believe what @KyleKanos meant by analytic solution was actually more like an exact closed form solution, without which we'd have to resort to numerically approximating solutions to differential equations, etc.

Comment: What @CuriousKev said is correct, by having some closed-form solutions to problems, we can test our *numerical algorithms* for accuracy (still going to be limited by precision, though). I'm currently unaware of any Planck-level models, but that's mostly because I'm an astrophysicist so I deal with parsec scales, rather than Planck.

Comment: Let me ask from another angle: Do *exact solutions* exist for real-world models at the scale of ℓP ? (Apologies, I'm programmer, not a physicist :))

Comment: Here's one I found from a simple Google search: http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.5712, so yes there are some exact solutions that exist.

Comment: @KyleKanos - nice find - thanks! You said 'simple google search' ... what string did you use? (When I tried before, all I got was unrelated Fokker-Planck equations.) BTW, it's interesting that you're working on the other end of the scale --- my real question, which this one is a part of, is 'precision aside, what are the *practical* limits of combinatoric models?' Clearly, if I'd asked *that*, the question would have slid negative as 'being too broad' :)))

Comment: @HowardPautz: My search string was `exact solution planck scale` and that was the first thing that popped up.

Comment: Also, [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7467) popped up on the arXiv this morning. It discusses sub-Planckian wavelengths in the context of inflation.